# How to validate so I would get message saying username already exists if I enter same username?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password, name } = req.body;

  // TODO: Validate if username exists
  
  await knex("users").insert({ username, password, name });
  
  const user = await knex("users").where({ username }).first();

  // const users = await knex("users").where({username});
  
  
  // if (users === username) {
  //   res.status(401).json({
  //     error: {
  //       message: "Username already exists"
  //     }
  //   })
  // } else {
    const token = jwt.sign({ username, id: user.id }, secret);
    console.log(token);
    res.json({ ...user, token });
  // }
};
```

I can't throw an error when I enter username  which already exist in database mySQL. It keeps crashing the server and doesn;t reach else

It keeps crashing the server and doesn't reach else.

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("users", (table) => {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string("username").notNullable().unique();
    table.string("password").notNullable();
    table.string("name").notNullable();
  });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("users");
};
```

username is unique.

Comment: Attempt the insert and catch the duplicate key error, then you know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can `try - catch` and analize the error code to see if it represents a [unique key constraint violation in mySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_dup_entry):

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password, name } = req.body;

  try {
    await knex('users').insert({ username, password, name });

    const user = await knex('users').where({ username }).first();

    const token = jwt.sign({ username, id: user.id }, secret);
    console.log(token);
    res.json({ ...user, token });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' || err.errno === 1062) {
      // User already exists...
    } else {
      // Server error...
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah. Thank you so much. Now I can see my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create `unique` constraint on `username` field in database.

`ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE (username);`

And try again with same username it will throw error of duplicate entry.